# Going beyond temperature rating for surface mounted resistor? Will it damage it?

Tags: resistors, temperature, vacuum

I am putting surface mounted resistors inside a vacuum chamber and then baking the vacuum chamber at 200°C for 2 weeks, no voltage will be applied to the resistors during this time. Will this damage the resistors if they are rated up to 155°C?

Comment: What resistors they are, do they have a data sheet?

Comment: Here is the data sheet: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/koa-speer-electronics-inc/WK73R1JTTD102J/10274596

Comment: The issue is the size, high temp resistors are normally very large. We are looking for something that is round 1 mm long and .5 wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without careful testing, there is essentially no way to know.

There are resistors out there rated for the temperature you're using it at.  For example, [THESE](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/r/riedon/high-temperature-chr-and-hvs-chip-resistors?utm_adgroup=Resistors&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_EN_Product&utm_term=&utm_content=Resistors&gclid=Cj0KCQjwzdOlBhCNARIsAPMwjbzOkLhj2PD0Zv8562yjMNHGF_j_g92gAHtzlupl7OXRo-xh4MTG6GIaAuMoEALw_wcB) at Digikey.  If it's important that your device works when it's powered up, I recommend using a high-temp option.

Comment: Was just typing out an answer with words to this affect. These components are normally only designed to withstand these temperatures temporarily while they are being soldered. 2 Weeks would be an eternity compared to the few minutes they get whilst being reflow soldered.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a few things. You should not go above the storage or operating temperature in the data sheet. so if it's 155C for a Max temperature then it's likely that you'll damage them at 200C.

Most smt components can tolerate more than the operating or storage temperature but only for a short time. They will specify this time in a reflow profile or specific the spec for the reflow profile.

If your resistors don't tolerate 200C get resistors that will.